# Google web fonts - how reliable are they?

Tags: webfonts, google-font-api

I use Google fonts quite a lot, especially ones like:-

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />`

Should these only be used for 'parts' of the web site or is it okay to use these for the content of the entire site?

`body {
    background-color:#292828;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}`

Also, is there any alternative/better ways to use custom fonts other than using Google fonts or images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own webfonts, if you want.

There's webfont generators, and [here's one.](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

---

And about your question about are google webfonts reliable?

Yes. Yes they're. Think it like this: When did Google go down? If it happens, it's probably the last thing you should care of.

Comment: That's true, I've noticed google fonts doesn't work on some mobile devices, like my old HD7 (windows phone) even though its running IE9

Comment: @nsilva You didn't ask about browser support. If they won't work on some browser, then that browser doesn't support them. Modern browsers support them.

Comment: some times, web fonts are not supported by a specific device or a specific web browser. In that case, you should always have a backup font included

Comment: @nsilva Here's an article about differences between WP7 IE9 and desktop IE9. http://www.ubelly.com/2011/11/the-differences-between-ie9-on-the-desktop-and-ie9-on-wp7/.

Comment: @SherKhan Here's a list of support for webfonts. http://caniuse.com/fontface Android 2.3 > support them partially, if provided with the stock android browser. iOS has had full support since 2nd generation devices.

Comment: @Christian +1 for u :)

Answer (score 1):

Google web-fonts are reliable. But if you want to use them and host them on your own server then simply go the stylesheet url. In your case, the urls is

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:200
```

when you visit it then you will see another url in it as follow:

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: local('Titillium WebThin'), local('TitilliumWeb-Thin'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v1/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr3XqdloEk0Ij5qwGW4qO9RM.woff) format('woff');
}
```

after that, copy the url from  it. in this case the url is:

```
http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v1/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr3XqdloEk0Ij5qwGW4qO9RM.woff
```

when u visit the url, a font file will get downloaded to your computer. upload that file to your web server and include it in your style sheet as follow:

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'any name of the font you wnat';

  src: url(the url to your file on your own server just like u link to  an image);
}
```

Now after inclusion, you can use it anywhere on your site where you desire and where the stylesheet is included by calling font-family: the  name of the font you used above;

Any doubt, please ask :)

Comment: I have done this myself for development as my internet is flakey at best. However it's not what you should be doing in production. AFAIK the Google Font system performs OS/Browser detection when you request the CSS so it can deliver a specific format font file. Having said that; The .woff format is supported by modern browsers, if older browsers are not your concern, it shouldn't cause a problem. HTH